# What steps can common people take to be prepared to sue anyone that does something wrong to them?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law

Are there some things that we can make a habit of doing that are gonna help us in winning a lawsuit we file in case a situation unexpectedly arrives where we need to seek relief from the law? For example: always have a recording pen in your shirt pocket, installing surveillance cameras in your home and office, backing up emails, text messages and chat history etc.

Comment: Where do you live? IIRC, in some locations it's illegal to record audio or video of other people without their consent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There are lots of intangibles in civil litigation, but one of the most valuable things you can do is maintain scrupulous records of any interactions with anyone whom you expect ot see in court.d Records you made throughout the course of the interactions are looked at more favorably than an account you assembled for the purpose of litigation, so you are at an advantage if you come in with a credible account of your relationship with a defendant who simply comes in and says, "I remember it differently."

Recording times, dates, and locations of conversations can be very helpful, and even more so if you do so in communications with the potential defendant. If he receives your accounts of the interactions and does not object to your characterizations, it helps build the case that your memory and interpretation of those interactions is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!